# Checked all if data name is the same

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to put checked if checkbox has the same data name

Like:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-name="| Фундамент" class="ch parent-id-151" name="id_category[]" value="152">

<input type="checkbox" data-name="| Фундамент" class="ch parent-id-152" name="id_category[]" value="153">

<input type="checkbox" data-name="| Фундамент" class="ch parent-id-153" name="id_category[]" value="154">
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(".ch").change(function(){
var dsa = jQuery(".ch").data("name");
 if (dsa.checked) {
        jQuery(dsa).prop('checked', true);
    }

});
```

But seems not to work...

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
if (dsa.checked) {
```

This shouldn't work, `dsa` is just a string with the data-name of the checked element. Also `checked` is not a valid property.

If I understand correctly that you always want to check all the checkboxes with the same name at once, try this:

```
jQuery(".ch").change(function(){
  var name = jQuery(this).data("name"); 
  var isChecked = jQuery(this).is(':checked');

  jQuery('[data-name="' + name + '"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all with the same data name by doing:

```
jQuery('.ch[data-name="| Фундамент"]')
```

which I think that `jQuery('.ch[data-name="| Фундамент"]').prop('checked', true);` will work for you after replacing '| Фундамент' with whatever data-name you are intending to check.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it like this:

```
jQuery(".ch").change(function(){
var dsa = jQuery(this).data("name");
        jQuery('[data-name="'+dsa+'"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```